# Does a Map.empty and a None take the same about of memory?

Tags: scala

If i have a case class that looks like:

```
case class User(id: String, settings: Map[String, String])
```

Will there be a difference in terms of memory footprint when I instantiate this object if I defined it like this:

```
case class User(id: String, settings: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])
```

versus

```
case class User(id: String, settings: Option[Map[String, String]] = None)
```

So we are comparing a case classes property being either an empty Map, or a None on a option type.

Is there a difference in terms of memory footprint on instances of `User`?

Comment: Note that `Option[Map]` means that the data can be empty in two ways, this may be desired but most of the time is better to use `Option[NonEmptyMap]`

Answer (score 4):

Both `None` and `Map.empty` are `objects` with no fields, so would have the same memory consumption (on a typical JVM, around 20 bytes is the right order of magnitude).

Note that modeling as an `Option[Map]` incurs overhead (on a typical JVM, something more like 30 bytes) for every non-empty case.  There's thus no memory savings by using `None` in place of an empty `Map`.

The only good reason, at least in my experience, to ever use an `Option[Map]` is in conjunction with things like macro-derived serialization, where you're modeling that the map might not even have a field in the serialized representation.

Answer (score 3):

`None` is an `object`. So, it is already created for you and is reused by every reference.

Now, the question is - which `Map` is this ? `mutable` or `immutable` ?

`immutable.Map.empty[A, B]` is similar to `None` in this way. Its just that it has more feilds and will "actually" take more memory, but this difference will be in `Bytes` and can be ignored.

Whereas `mutable.Map.empty[A, B]()` will create a new empty map object everytime, you create any instance of this `User`. So, `None` will result in less memory compared to `mutable.Map.empty[A, B]()`.

Comment: AFAICT, at least as of 2.13.6, looking through the source code, I don't see any fields in `scala.collection.immutable.Map.EmptyMap`, which is what `Map.empty` returns.

Comment: I was not talking about class value members. `Map` has two type parameter, which will be "represented" by `class` instances at runtime. I was talking about these "fields".

Comment: AFAIK, the JVM doesn't store class instances of the associated types, do you have a cite for that?  (and on bytecode inspection, there's no compiler-generated injection of class instances)